# Drawing regular Polygon

Tags: geometry, computational-geometry

A regular polygon with **N** vertices. The lower side of the polygon is parallel to **x** axis. Given two point **(x1, y1)** and **(x2, y2)** if we draw a line through these points then the line would be parallel to the **x** axis. That means the lower side of the polygon is given. How to find the other **n - 2** points. Each point could have floating value but it is grantee that **x1, y1, x2, y2** is integer.

As example if **N = 5** and (x1, y1) = (0, 0) and (x2, y2) = (5, 0)

I have to find these remaining 3 points (6.545085, 4.755283), (2.500000, 7.694209), (-1.545085 4.755283)

I am trying with vector rotation, but can't figure out any solution. How can I calculate ?

Comment: Other than geometry are you using some computing tool? If yours is just a math problem, this forum is not very good for it. Try http://math.stackexchange.com/

Comment: You have the vertex coordinates, so what is the problem ?

Comment: To find the other vertex coordinates ?

Comment: You have the five, what more ?

Comment: I don't understand your question clearly. Here I ask - There is an N vertices regular polygon two vertices are given you have to find other N-2 vertices.

Comment: I edit the question, I think it's clear now.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is about [math.se] instead of programming or software development.

Comment: Yes it's about Mathematics, but its also about [programming](https://algo.codemarshal.org/contests/sustiupc2015/problems/L). You are not allowed to see the question you can see input output

Answer (score 0):

Given points x1, y1, x2, y2, number N.
Middle point of this edge is

```
xm = (x1 + x2) / 2
ym = y1
```

The center of polygon has coordinates

```
xc = xm
yc = y1 + Abs(x1 - x2)/2 * Ctg(Pi/N)
```

Radius of circumcircle is (**Edit: 0.5 coefficient was missed**)

```
R = 0.5 * Abs(x1 - x2) / Sin(Pi/N)
```

Kth (k=3..N) vertice of polygon has coordinates

```
xk = xc + R * Cos(-Pi/2 + Pi/N + (k - 2) * 2 * Pi/ N)
yk = yc + R * Sin(-Pi/2 + Pi/N + (k - 2) * 2 * Pi/ N)
```

Comment: Cotangent = 1/Tangent